# AppCenter Build: Project {project-name} at : is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping

Tags: android, build, yaml, appcenter

I'm really confused at AppCenter Build's behavior. I successfully created a GitHub Action to build an Android project but when I point AppCenter to that repository, I get the following:

`Project AndroidDummy1 at : is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping...`

...where "AndroidDummy1" is the test project I'm working with, a very simple one-screen app just to debug and test the AppCenter build process. More of the log looks like this:

```
Welcome to Gradle 8.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Kotlin DSL: new reference documentation, assignment syntax by default
 - Kotlin DSL is now the default with Gradle init
 - Improved suggestions to resolve errors in console output

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Gradle 8.2

> Configure project :
Resolved com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.0 in detachedConfiguration1 
Resolved org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.9.0 in detachedConfiguration2 
Resolved com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.0 in :classpath 
Resolved org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.9.0 in :classpath 
Project AndroidDummy1 at : is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AndroidDummy1'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.0
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12)
##[error]Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
##[section]Finishing: Gradle Task
```

I tried to find the YAML that I assume AppCenter generates, but the closest I could come to seeing what AppCenter fired off was when I looked at the configuration options, and opened the "Export Branch Configuration" window, and looked in the "YAML export configuration" section. I see all the steps that AppCenter uses, but it appears that's a one-way display - I can't alter that script to tweak to find a working solution. And in the "Advanced Build Configuration" section above it, it says this:

"Azure Pipeline supports more advanced build configurations than App Center Build. If your application has complex repository structure or requires customizations using a framework that’s not supported by App Center, try setting up Azure Pipelines that may better serve your application."

And then it goes on for a little bit.

Does this mean I have to migrate to Azure Pipelines in order to fire off an AppCenter build successfully? I don't understand why there's apparently a null reference in the error message (at the colon): "Project AndroidDummy1 at : is"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement in the documentation "[**Building Java apps for Android**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/)" and "[**Gradle build after JCenter shutdown**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/jcentershut)", the recent shutdown of JCenter may cause the similar Gradle Task failures.

[image]

If you use JCenter and Bintray resources in your AppCenter Android builds, the Gradle Task failures in your build could be related to this.

---